# Composição: usar @class ou #import?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, objective-c

Recentemente tive um problema de `Unknow type name 'Class'`, pois estava fazendo *import* no *header* de 2 classes. Descobri que esse é um erro clássico de *headers* importando *headers*.

Fui orientado a mudar o `import` de uma das classes para @class e na classe de implementação (.m) fazer a importação.

Minha pergunta é: quando usar `@class` ou `#import`? Eu poderia apagar os *imports* de todas minhas classes que fazem referência a outras classes e simplesmente escrever `@class` e aí sim importá-las no *implementation file*?

Answer (score 4):

Aqui vai uma resposta sumariada (e não 100% correcta). Este assunto é bastante extenso para explicar num post, se não ficares satisfeito terás de ser tu a pesquisar para aprofundar a questão. Só quero dar-te uma ideia simples, aconselho que aprofundes mais o assunto.

Mas primeiro, vou supor que não sabes C e dar uma breve explicação em como o código é transformado em app.

Podemos dizer que existem 3 passos (na verdade são mais, mas conhecer estes três é o suficiente para ter uma boa noção do processo):

**1) Pré-compilação**

Isto é quando o código é preparado para compilação, quando as directivas `#define`, `#ifdef`, etc. são processadas. Ou seja, se tivermos um `#define MyDef 3`, ao fim deste passo todos os sítios do código com `MyDef` terão 3.

É também este passo que gere as redefinições de macros, por exemplo, se tivermos os ficheiros `a.h`

```
#define MyDef 3
```

e `b.h`

```
#define MyDef 4
```

Quando usarmos o `MyDef`, o seu valor dependerá na ordem em que incluímos os `headers`.

```
#import "a.h"
#import "b.h"
// MyDef == 4

#import "b.h"
#import "a.h"
// MyDef == 3
```

**2) Compilação**

Este é o sumo de todo o processo, por isso é que se chama de compilação também aos três passos juntos, porque este é o principal.

É este passo que transforma o código em linguagem máquina. Este passo resulta em ficheiros binários como código executável. Tem os bytes que o processador irá interpretar durante a execução para saber o que fazer.

Estes binários parciais têm também referências para os outros binários parciais e bibliotecas do iOS (as .framework).

**3) Linking**

Este é o último passo. É quando todos os binários parciais resultantes do 2 são juntos num só executável.

É também aqui que os recursos são adicionados ao binário final.

---

Ao usar a directiva `@class` estamos a dizer ao compilador que a classe existe e que não é preciso verificar a sua existência, delegando essa verificação para o `linking`.

Por exemplo:

```
@class XPTO;
@interface YPTO : NSObject
    @property (strong, nonatomic) XPTO *xpto;
    //...
@end
```

Este `.h` diz ao compilador não te preocupes com a XPTO isso será tratado no `linking`.

Isto tem um problema, não tendo uma referência para a classe, o compilador não a sabe usar. Por isso, no `.m` adicionamos o `#import`:

```
#import "YPTO.h"
#import "XPTO.h"
@implementation YPTO
    - (void)yMethod
    {
        [xpto xMethod];
    }
    //...
@end
```

Sem o `#import`, o compilador não sabe qual a referência do método `xMethod` a usar quando criar o binário parcial do YPTO. Isto pode ser visto da seguinte maneira. A directiva `@interface` cria as referências, se o compilador não lê a `@interface` não sabe quais as referências a usar.

O que acontece é que o compilador (e também o pré-compilador) quando percorre o `YPTO.m` irá *i)* ler o `YPTO.h`, *ii)* ler o `XPTO.h` e *ii)* ler a `@implementation YPTO`.

---

> Quando usar `@class` ou `#import`?

Usa o `@class` quando não precisas do `#import`.

Pessoalmente, tento ter o mínimo de `#import`s nos `.h` possível. Usando o exemplo das classes XPTO e YPTO. Imagina que mais tarde criamos uma classe ZPTO que usa a YPTO, mas não precisa da XPTO. Ao fazermos o `#import "YPTO.h"`, o compilador não perderá tempo a ler o `XPTO,h` nem os `#import`s dele.

Outra vantagem é que reduzimos a possibilidade de termos, por exemplo,

a.h

```
#import "b.h"
```

b.h

```
#import "a.h"
```

Onde ao ler o `a.h`, o compilador iria ler o `b.h`, que por sua vez faria o compilador ler o `a.h`, `b.h`, `a.h`, *ad infinitum*.

---

> Eu poderia apagar os *imports* de todas minhas classes que fazem referência a outras classes e simplesmente escrever `@class` e aí sim importá-las no *implementation file*?

Vou supor que quando falas em apagar das classes te referes aos `.h`.

A reposta parece ser "sim, podes". Mas há duas coisas a ter em atenção.

**Primeiro, não é boa ideia.**

Sei que parece ir em contradição com o que respondi à outra questão, mas o que disse foi que pessoalmente tento ter o mínimo de `#import`s nos `.h` possível.

Por vezes é preferível ter `#import`s no `.h`.

Voltando ao exemplo das classes XPTO e YPTO. Imagina que todos os métodos da YPTO recebem e/ou retornam instâncias de XPTO. É muito provável que quem importe o `YPTO.h` também queira importar o `XPTO.h`, viste que YTPO tem uma relação de dependência da XPTO. Neste caso fará sentido que o `#import "XPTO.h"` esteja no `YPTO.h`.

**Segundo, não podes.**

Embora pareça que sim, existem situações onde tal não é possível.

```
@class Super
@interface Class : Super
    //...
@end
```

Neste exemplo, o compilador não terá uma referência para a classe Super e não saberá como resolver a herança.

---

Como extra, quero avisar que se quiseres fazer algo semelhante ao `@class` para protocolos, podes fazê-lo com o `@protocol`.

Por exemplo,

```
@protocol Delegate;
@interface Class : NSObject
    @proprety (weak, nonatomic) id<Delegate> delegate;
    //...
@end
```

No entanto, não é possível fazer

```
@protocol Delegate;
@interface Class : NSObject <Delegate>
    //...
@end
```

pois o compilador não terá a referência do protocolo.

Answer (score 3):

> Minha pergunta é: quando usar `@class` ou `#import`?

- @Class: É usado quando queremos declarar um objeto de uma classe qualquer.

  // File: CadastroAnimal.h

  @class Animal;
  @interface CadastroAnimal : UIViewController {
      Animal*   _animal;
  }
  @end
- ## import: É usado quando queremos usar os métodos de qualquer classe ou queremos definir o delegado para esta classe.

  //File: CadastroAnimal.h

  ## import Animal.h

  @interface CadastroAnimal : UIViewController
  {
     Animal*   _animal;
  }

---

> Eu poderia apagar os `imports` de todas minhas classes que fazem referência a outras classes e simplesmente escrever `@class` e aí sim importá-las no implementation file?

Fazendo isso quer dizer que não queremos usar os métodos da classe "Animal" neste momento, nem queremos definir o delegado de classe `"Animal.h"`. Daí podemos usar isso para aumentar a velocidade do compilador.

Se usar o `#import "Animal.h"` e não for definir o delegado da classe é melhor fazer a importação somente no *implementation file*, já que utilizaremos seus métodos apenas neste arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

No seu header file, quando você precisa se referenciar a uma classe você usa o @class, já dentro do seu source você vai utilizar a classe e não somente referenciá-la, então você usa #import